# Conversion of html textarea to laravel 4.2 textarea

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Hi im using ckeditor so i currently have the html version which is

```
<textarea class="ckeditor" name="editor" id = "stuff">

        {{ $opendoc }}

    </textarea>
```

the `$opendoc` came from my controller. it contains txt in my controller it looks like this

$fname = $file->filename;

```
    $opendoc = file_get_contents(public_path('uploads/docs/' . $fname));

    return View::make('dmy.open_doc' , compact('title', 'smpl' , 'opendoc'));
```

im trying to display the data using laravel 4.2 textarea 
currently im using something like this

```
{{ Form::textarea('open_file', $opendoc , array('class' => 'ckeditor')) }}
```

but the value of `$opendoc`could not be viewed. any ideas what im doing wrong? thanks in advance

Comment: Do you get something by dumping the $opendoc variable on your view?

Comment: hello. yes im getting the string being passed by the controller. it also works when im using it with the html version of textarea. I already checked the documentation an d it said that the format should be Form::textarea('name', $value, array('class' => 'name')); which im following so i don really know where im wrong

Comment: Is there really a reason that you need to change to that? I mean, the `Form` helper class almost ends up producing just as much code with a less clean syntax, especially when it comes to `Form::select`. It was also removed in newer versions of Laravel for this reason. I would recommend not using the Form class in this case.

Comment: @BourneShady What do You mean by saying "could not be viewed"? Is it just empty textarea input or some kind of error occurs?

Comment: hi @GiedriusKiršys it just shows the textarea but without any contents

Comment: hi @Ohgodwhy i actually tried that but i just wanted to make it in a laravel way by using the form helper

Comment: Just wild guess, but can You confirm that `Input::old('open_file')` returns `null` in view?

Answer (score 1):

It just shows the textarea but without any contents - check whether that variable is set or not.

```
{!! Form::textarea('open_file', isset($opendoc)? $opendoc:null, array('class' => 'ckeditor','size' => '10x3')) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use the Form::textarea() method.
```

The simplest usage is to only pass a single argument, the name.

```
{{ Form::textarea('notes') }}
```

This produces the following HTML.

```
<textarea name="notes" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Notice the default cols and rows.

You can pass the value as the second argument.

```
{{ Form::textarea('notes', '3 < 4') }}
```

The value will be escaped.

```
<textarea name="notes" cols="50" rows="10">3 &lt; 4</textarea>
```

Additional options can be passed as a third argument. This must be an array.

```
{{ Form::textarea('notes', null, ['class' => 'field']) }}
```

This will add the class "field" to the text area.

Your solution

```
{!! Form::textarea('open_file', isset($opendoc)? $opendoc:null, array('class' => 'ckeditor','size' => '10x3')) !!}
```